# Primes in the form $n^{k}+n-1$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Lately I've been (very casually) toying with primes in the form $n^k+n-1$, as a very far-reaching generalization of Fermat primes. (you get a Fermat prime when you set $k=2^m$ and $n=2$). I have little training in number theory, so mainly I've been just typing stuff into Wolfram and searching for patterns.

One thing I started doing was looking for the smallest $k$ such that $n^k+n-1$ is prime for any particular $n$. I've been able to find solutions for $n \leq 106$. Obviously $k=1$ and $k=2$ do a lot of heavy lifting, but there are some remarkable numbers here. The one that stunned me the most upon finding it was $32^{108}+31 \approx 3.6 \times 10^{162}$, but there's an even bigger smallest solution: $80^{194}+79 \approx 1.58 \times 10^{369}$.

For $n=107$, there are no solutions for $k \leq 495$, which is about as far as I can reliably check.  Obviously any $k$ that works must be divisible by $4$.

So, three things I wonder about are:

1. Is any solution for $n=107$ known? Does it exist for sure?
2. In general, has it been shown that there is a solution for any $n$?
3. For any $k$ not in the form $6m+5$, is there $n$ such that $k$ is the smallest solution?

EDIT:

Let $f(n)$ be any polynomial $\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$. Let $\text{GCD}[f]$ denote the greatest common divisor of $\{f(n): n \in \mathbb N\}$. There is this long-standing conjecture by Bouniakowsky that $f$ is irreducible iff there are infinitely many numbers $n$ such that $\frac{f(n)}{\text{GCD}[f]}$ is prime.

If we suppose this is true, then the following statement implies a positive answer to question 3:

For any $k: k \not \equiv 5 \pmod 6$ there are natural numbers $\alpha,\beta$ such that $\text{GCD}[(\alpha n+\beta)^k+(\alpha n+\beta)-1]=1$, but $\text{GCD}[(\alpha n + \beta)^m+(\alpha n + \beta)-1] \neq 1$ for any $m<k: m \not \equiv 5 \pmod 6$.

Example: for $k=3$, one can let $\alpha = 15, \beta = 2$.

To my untrained eye, this seems approachable.

Comment: Unsurprizingly, turns out the sequence is known in OEIS as A076845; but the list ends at 100

Comment: There are several powerful tools to check primality : PFGW , LLR and PARI/GP which is however slower, but more flexible. However, there should already be tables for this kind of prime numbers somewhere in the internet. You can also lookup the numbers in factordb.

Comment: For $n=107$ and $k=1400$ , we get a prime number (I have not yet proven the primality, but a Miller rabin test with $40$ bases was successful). I am pretty sure that $2$ and $3$ are open questions without a hope to answer them.

Comment: Why do you exclude $k=6m+5$ in $3$ ?

Comment: @MichałZapała. For $1$ to $100$ it is almost immediate. After, it takes a lot of time.

Comment: A few more $\{2,44,2,14,3,1,1400,6,3,4,6,1,1\}$

Comment: @Peter, $n^{6m+5}+n-1$ is divisible by $n^2-n+1$.

Comment: My general gut feeling is that both 2. and 3. are true, and that if 2. is assumed then 3. is tough but provable. 2 seems nasty indeed, probably similarly so to some well-established nasty conjectures in number theory.

A far more general question would be about numbers in the form $n^m+k$, where $n$ is odd, $k$ is even, and $n$ are $k$ are coprime.

Comment: I have proven the primality for $n=107$ and $k=1400$

Comment: There is a mistake on @ClaudeLeibovici list: it states $k=1$ for $n=113$, which is obviously not true since we get $113^1+112=225$. $n=113$ seems to be another tricky number. Other than that his table is fine. After $113$ is goes $\{1,1,6,1,6,4,1,1,4\}$ and another enigma at $n=123$.

Regarding conjecture $3$, one notable missing piece is $n$ such that $k=9$ is the smallest solution.

Comment: See edit for a potential approach to (conditionally) proving 3.

Answer (score 4):

> Not a 'real' answer, but it was too big for a comment. I think that you're looking for a solution without using a calculator or PC but maybe this gives some insight. I did only a quick search with the following bounds: $1\le\text{n}\le10^3$ and $1\le\text{k}\le10$.

I wrote and ran some [Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica)-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
\[Alpha] = 10^3;
\[Beta] = 10^1;
ParallelTable[
  If[PrimeQ[n^k + n - 1], {n, k}, Nothing], {n, 1, \[Alpha]}, {k, 
   1, \[Beta]}] //. {} -> Nothing
```

Running the code gives:

```
Out[1]={{{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 8}}, {{3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 
   4}, {3, 8}, {3, 10}}, {{4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}, {4, 6}, {4, 8}, {4, 
   9}}, {{5, 2}, {5, 6}, {5, 10}}, {{6, 1}, {6, 2}, {6, 4}, {6, 
   7}, {6, 10}}, {{7, 1}, {7, 3}}, {{8, 2}, {8, 6}, {8, 10}}, {{9, 
   1}, {9, 2}, {9, 4}, {9, 7}, {9, 10}}, {{10, 1}, {10, 2}, {10, 
   3}, {10, 4}, {10, 9}}, {{11, 2}, {11, 8}}, {{12, 1}, {12, 
   4}}, {{13, 2}, {13, 4}, {13, 10}}, {{15, 1}, {15, 2}, {15, 3}, {15,
    9}}, {{16, 1}, {16, 2}, {16, 3}, {16, 4}, {16, 8}, {16, 
   10}}, {{17, 4}, {17, 8}}, {{18, 3}, {18, 6}}, {{19, 1}, {19, 
   2}}, {{20, 2}, {20, 4}}, {{21, 1}, {21, 2}, {21, 3}}, {{22, 
   1}, {22, 7}}, {{23, 4}, {23, 6}}, {{24, 1}, {24, 2}, {24, 
   10}}, {{25, 3}, {25, 8}}, {{26, 2}, {26, 4}, {26, 10}}, {{27, 
   1}, {27, 3}, {27, 8}}, {{28, 2}, {28, 4}}, {{29, 10}}, {{30, 
   1}, {30, 2}, {30, 7}}, {{31, 1}, {31, 2}, {31, 4}, {31, 6}, {31, 
   10}}, {{33, 3}, {33, 4}}, {{34, 1}, {34, 6}}, {{35, 2}}, {{36, 
   1}, {36, 3}, {36, 6}}, {{37, 1}, {37, 7}}, {{38, 2}}, {{39, 
   2}, {39, 3}}, {{40, 1}, {40, 4}, {40, 10}}, {{41, 2}}, {{42, 
   1}}, {{43, 3}, {43, 4}}, {{44, 2}, {44, 4}}, {{45, 1}, {45, 
   2}}, {{46, 2}, {46, 3}, {46, 8}}, {{48, 2}}, {{49, 1}, {49, 
   7}, {49, 9}}, {{50, 2}, {50, 6}, {50, 8}}, {{51, 1}, {51, 3}, {51, 
   6}, {51, 10}}, {{52, 1}, {52, 3}}, {{53, 2}, {53, 6}}, {{54, 
   1}, {54, 2}, {54, 4}}, {{55, 1}, {55, 2}, {55, 3}}, {{56, 2}, {56, 
   6}}, {{57, 1}, {57, 9}}, {{58, 4}}, {{59, 2}, {59, 10}}, {{60, 
   2}, {60, 6}}, {{61, 7}, {61, 9}}, {{62, 8}}, {{63, 3}, {63, 
   6}}, {{64, 1}, {64, 2}}, {{65, 2}}, {{66, 1}, {66, 2}, {66, 
   8}, {66, 9}}, {{68, 2}, {68, 8}}, {{69, 1}, {69, 6}}, {{70, 
   1}, {70, 2}, {70, 7}, {70, 9}}, {{72, 4}}, {{73, 3}, {73, 
   6}}, {{74, 8}}, {{75, 1}, {75, 6}}, {{76, 1}, {76, 2}, {76, 
   6}, {76, 10}}, {{77, 4}, {77, 8}}, {{78, 3}}, {{79, 1}, {79, 
   9}}, {{81, 3}}, {{82, 1}}, {{83, 2}, {83, 6}}, {{84, 1}, {84, 
   8}}, {{85, 2}}, {{86, 2}}, {{87, 1}, {87, 3}, {87, 8}}, {{88, 
   8}}, {{89, 2}, {89, 10}}, {{90, 1}, {90, 10}}, {{91, 1}, {91, 
   6}}, {{92, 4}}, {{93, 2}, {93, 3}, {93, 4}, {93, 7}}, {{94, 
   2}, {94, 3}}, {{96, 1}, {96, 2}, {96, 3}, {96, 6}, {96, 10}}, {{97,
    1}}, {{98, 4}}, {{99, 1}, {99, 10}}, {{100, 1}, {100, 2}, {100, 
   3}, {100, 7}, {100, 8}}, {{101, 2}}, {{103, 2}, {103, 3}, {103, 
   10}}, {{105, 3}, {105, 4}, {105, 7}, {105, 9}}, {{106, 1}}, {{108, 
   6}}, {{109, 3}}, {{110, 4}}, {{111, 6}, {111, 8}}, {{112, 1}, {112,
    3}, {112, 9}}, {{114, 1}, {114, 2}, {114, 9}}, {{115, 1}, {115, 
   2}, {115, 3}, {115, 7}}, {{116, 6}}, {{117, 1}, {117, 3}, {117, 
   4}, {117, 8}}, {{118, 6}, {118, 7}, {118, 8}}, {{119, 4}}, {{120, 
   1}, {120, 2}, {120, 3}, {120, 4}, {120, 10}}, {{121, 1}, {121, 
   9}}, {{122, 4}, {122, 8}}, {{124, 3}, {124, 10}}, {{125, 2}, {125, 
   4}, {125, 8}}, {{126, 1}, {126, 2}, {126, 8}}, {{127, 3}}, {{129, 
   1}, {129, 3}}, {{130, 2}}, {{131, 2}}, {{132, 1}, {132, 4}, {132, 
   7}, {132, 8}}, {{133, 8}}, {{134, 2}, {134, 10}}, {{135, 1}, {135, 
   3}, {135, 6}}, {{136, 1}}, {{138, 2}}, {{139, 1}, {139, 3}}, {{140,
    2}, {140, 8}}, {{141, 1}, {141, 2}}, {{142, 1}, {142, 7}, {142, 
   9}}, {{143, 4}, {143, 6}}, {{144, 2}, {144, 9}}, {{145, 2}, {145, 
   3}}, {{146, 8}}, {{147, 1}, {147, 9}}, {{148, 2}, {148, 6}}, {{149,
    2}, {149, 8}}, {{150, 3}}, {{151, 3}}, {{153, 2}, {153, 
   8}}, {{154, 1}, {154, 2}}, {{155, 2}, {155, 10}}, {{156, 
   1}}, {{157, 1}, {157, 4}}, {{158, 2}}, {{159, 1}, {159, 2}, {159, 
   6}, {159, 7}}, {{160, 2}, {160, 8}}, {{162, 8}}, {{163, 2}, {163, 
   7}}, {{164, 2}, {164, 4}, {164, 8}, {164, 10}}, {{165, 3}, {165, 
   8}, {165, 9}}, {{166, 1}, {166, 3}, {166, 9}}, {{168, 8}, {168, 
   10}}, {{169, 1}, {169, 2}, {169, 7}}, {{171, 2}, {171, 3}, {171, 
   8}}, {{172, 9}}, {{174, 1}, {174, 2}, {174, 9}}, {{175, 1}}, {{176,
    2}}, {{177, 1}}, {{178, 3}, {178, 10}}, {{180, 1}, {180, 2}, {180,
    7}, {180, 8}}, {{181, 2}, {181, 8}}, {{182, 4}}, {{183, 6}, {183, 
   8}}, {{184, 1}, {184, 2}, {184, 7}}, {{185, 10}}, {{186, 
   2}}, {{187, 1}}, {{188, 2}, {188, 6}, {188, 8}}, {{189, 3}, {189, 
   6}}, {{190, 1}}, {{191, 2}, {191, 6}}, {{192, 1}, {192, 3}}, {{193,
    2}}, {{195, 1}, {195, 2}}, {{196, 2}, {196, 7}}, {{198, 
   3}}, {{199, 1}, {199, 2}, {199, 3}, {199, 9}}, {{201, 1}, {201, 
   4}, {201, 6}}, {{202, 3}}, {{203, 2}}, {{204, 3}, {204, 4}}, {{205,
    1}, {205, 4}}, {{206, 2}, {206, 6}}, {{208, 7}}, {{209, 2}, {209, 
   8}}, {{210, 1}}, {{211, 1}, {211, 7}}, {{215, 2}}, {{216, 1}, {216,
    3}, {216, 8}, {216, 9}}, {{217, 1}}, {{218, 2}}, {{219, 
   2}}, {{220, 1}, {220, 2}}, {{221, 8}}, {{222, 1}}, {{223, 
   3}}, {{225, 1}, {225, 2}}, {{228, 3}}, {{229, 1}, {229, 4}, {229, 
   9}}, {{230, 2}, {230, 6}, {230, 8}, {230, 10}}, {{231, 1}, {231, 
   2}, {231, 4}, {231, 6}}, {{232, 1}}, {{233, 2}}, {{234, 1}, {234, 
   6}}, {{235, 8}}, {{236, 2}}, {{240, 1}, {240, 2}}, {{241, 2}, {241,
    3}}, {{243, 3}}, {{244, 1}, {244, 2}, {244, 9}}, {{246, 1}, {246, 
   2}, {246, 3}}, {{247, 7}}, {{248, 2}, {248, 6}, {248, 8}}, {{250, 
   1}}, {{252, 1}}, {{253, 8}}, {{254, 6}, {254, 8}}, {{255, 1}, {255,
    6}, {255, 7}}, {{256, 9}}, {{258, 2}, {258, 3}}, {{259, 2}, {259, 
   3}, {259, 7}}, {{260, 6}, {260, 8}}, {{261, 1}}, {{262, 1}}, {{263,
    2}}, {{264, 2}}, {{265, 2}, {265, 8}}, {{266, 4}}, {{268, 
   2}}, {{271, 1}, {271, 6}}, {{274, 1}}, {{275, 4}}, {{276, 
   7}}, {{279, 1}, {279, 4}}, {{280, 8}}, {{281, 2}}, {{282, 
   1}}, {{283, 3}}, {{285, 1}, {285, 2}, {285, 3}}, {{286, 1}, {286, 
   3}, {286, 4}}, {{288, 2}, {288, 4}}, {{289, 1}, {289, 6}}, {{290, 
   2}, {290, 4}, {290, 8}}, {{291, 9}}, {{292, 4}, {292, 8}}, {{293, 
   4}}, {{294, 1}, {294, 2}}, {{296, 2}}, {{297, 1}}, {{298, 
   2}}, {{300, 1}, {300, 3}}, {{301, 1}, {301, 2}}, {{303, 2}}, {{304,
    1}, {304, 4}}, {{305, 2}, {305, 6}}, {{306, 2}}, {{307, 1}, {307, 
   7}}, {{308, 10}}, {{309, 1}, {309, 2}, {309, 4}}, {{310, 1}, {310, 
   3}, {310, 8}}, {{312, 8}}, {{313, 3}}, {{314, 2}}, {{316, 1}, {316,
    3}}, {{318, 4}}, {{319, 2}, {319, 3}}, {{321, 1}, {321, 
   4}}, {{322, 1}, {322, 4}}, {{323, 2}, {323, 6}}, {{324, 1}, {324, 
   10}}, {{326, 8}}, {{327, 1}, {327, 7}, {327, 8}}, {{328, 
   6}}, {{329, 4}}, {{330, 1}, {330, 2}, {330, 4}, {330, 9}}, {{331, 
   1}, {331, 2}, {331, 6}}, {{334, 3}, {334, 4}}, {{335, 2}}, {{336, 
   10}}, {{337, 1}}, {{339, 1}, {339, 2}, {339, 10}}, {{342, 
   1}}, {{343, 2}, {343, 3}}, {{344, 4}}, {{346, 1}, {346, 9}}, {{348,
    3}, {348, 6}}, {{349, 2}, {349, 6}}, {{350, 2}, {350, 4}}, {{351, 
   1}, {351, 2}, {351, 4}, {351, 10}}, {{352, 3}, {352, 7}}, {{353, 
   4}}, {{354, 2}}, {{355, 1}}, {{356, 8}}, {{358, 2}}, {{360, 
   1}, {360, 2}, {360, 3}, {360, 8}}, {{361, 2}}, {{363, 4}}, {{364, 
   1}, {364, 2}}, {{366, 3}, {366, 4}, {366, 10}}, {{367, 1}, {367, 
   3}, {367, 8}}, {{370, 1}, {370, 9}}, {{371, 6}}, {{372, 1}}, {{373,
    2}, {373, 4}, {373, 6}}, {{374, 2}}, {{375, 6}}, {{376, 1}, {376, 
   3}}, {{378, 2}}, {{379, 1}, {379, 3}}, {{380, 2}, {380, 6}}, {{381,
    1}, {381, 3}, {381, 7}}, {{385, 1}, {385, 2}, {385, 6}, {385, 
   7}, {385, 8}}, {{386, 2}, {386, 6}}, {{387, 1}, {387, 7}, {387, 
   9}}, {{390, 4}}, {{391, 2}, {391, 3}}, {{393, 2}, {393, 6}, {393, 
   8}}, {{394, 1}}, {{395, 2}, {395, 10}}, {{396, 2}}, {{397, 
   4}}, {{398, 4}, {398, 8}}, {{399, 1}, {399, 4}}, {{401, 2}, {401, 
   6}}, {{405, 1}, {405, 2}}, {{406, 1}, {406, 4}, {406, 7}}, {{407, 
   4}}, {{408, 2}, {408, 4}, {408, 7}}, {{409, 4}, {409, 8}}, {{411, 
   1}}, {{412, 1}, {412, 3}}, {{414, 1}, {414, 6}}, {{415, 1}}, {{417,
    3}}, {{418, 2}, {418, 3}}, {{419, 2}}, {{420, 1}, {420, 2}, {420, 
   6}}, {{421, 3}}, {{423, 2}, {423, 8}}, {{424, 3}, {424, 8}}, {{426,
    3}, {426, 8}}, {{427, 1}}, {{428, 2}}, {{429, 1}, {429, 3}, {429, 
   8}}, {{430, 1}, {430, 3}}, {{431, 2}}, {{432, 1}, {432, 3}}, {{433,
    2}}, {{434, 8}}, {{435, 9}}, {{437, 8}}, {{438, 6}}, {{439, 
   1}, {439, 10}}, {{440, 8}}, {{441, 1}}, {{442, 1}}, {{443, 
   6}}, {{444, 1}, {444, 3}}, {{445, 2}}, {{446, 8}}, {{447, 
   8}}, {{448, 2}}, {{449, 2}}, {{450, 2}, {450, 3}}, {{451, 
   8}}, {{453, 2}}, {{454, 1}, {454, 3}}, {{455, 2}, {455, 4}}, {{456,
    1}, {456, 2}, {456, 7}}, {{459, 3}}, {{460, 1}, {460, 4}, {460, 
   6}}, {{461, 2}}, {{462, 7}}, {{463, 2}, {463, 4}}, {{465, 
   1}}, {{466, 3}, {466, 6}}, {{468, 2}, {468, 3}}, {{469, 1}, {469, 
   3}, {469, 4}, {469, 6}}, {{471, 1}, {471, 2}, {471, 6}}, {{472, 
   3}, {472, 4}, {472, 9}}, {{473, 2}, {473, 8}}, {{474, 1}, {474, 
   2}}, {{475, 2}}, {{477, 1}}, {{478, 2}}, {{481, 2}, {481, 
   3}}, {{482, 4}}, {{483, 4}, {483, 7}}, {{484, 1}, {484, 3}}, {{486,
    1}, {486, 2}, {486, 3}, {486, 9}}, {{489, 1}, {489, 3}, {489, 
   9}, {489, 10}}, {{490, 2}}, {{492, 1}}, {{493, 6}}, {{494, 
   2}, {494, 6}}, {{495, 2}, {495, 9}}, {{496, 1}, {496, 2}}, {{499, 
   1}, {499, 2}, {499, 7}}, {{500, 2}}, {{501, 2}}, {{502, 4}}, {{504,
    2}}, {{505, 1}, {505, 3}}, {{506, 2}, {506, 4}}, {{507, 1}, {507, 
   4}}, {{508, 6}}, {{510, 1}, {510, 2}, {510, 3}}, {{511, 1}, {511, 
   2}}, {{513, 4}}, {{514, 3}, {514, 10}}, {{515, 2}, {515, 
   6}}, {{516, 1}, {516, 4}}, {{517, 1}}, {{518, 2}}, {{519, 2}, {519,
    8}}, {{520, 1}, {520, 4}, {520, 6}}, {{521, 4}, {521, 10}}, {{522,
    3}}, {{524, 4}}, {{525, 1}, {525, 6}}, {{526, 1}}, {{528, 
   2}, {528, 3}, {528, 7}, {528, 10}}, {{529, 9}}, {{530, 2}}, {{531, 
   1}}, {{532, 1}, {532, 3}, {532, 7}}, {{534, 4}}, {{535, 1}, {535, 
   3}, {535, 4}}, {{537, 9}}, {{538, 3}, {538, 4}, {538, 7}}, {{539, 
   4}}, {{540, 6}, {540, 7}}, {{541, 2}, {541, 3}}, {{542, 4}}, {{543,
    8}}, {{544, 1}, {544, 2}, {544, 6}, {544, 8}, {544, 9}, {544, 
   10}}, {{546, 1}, {546, 7}}, {{547, 1}}, {{548, 2}}, {{549, 
   1}, {549, 2}}, {{550, 2}}, {{551, 2}, {551, 6}}, {{552, 1}}, {{553,
    3}, {553, 4}}, {{554, 4}, {554, 8}}, {{555, 1}, {555, 4}, {555, 
   6}, {555, 8}}, {{556, 4}}, {{558, 3}, {558, 10}}, {{559, 1}, {559, 
   6}, {559, 9}}, {{560, 2}}, {{561, 2}, {561, 4}}, {{562, 1}, {562, 
   3}, {562, 4}}, {{564, 9}}, {{565, 1}, {565, 8}}, {{566, 
   10}}, {{567, 4}, {567, 8}}, {{568, 3}}, {{569, 2}}, {{571, 
   2}}, {{572, 4}}, {{573, 2}, {573, 4}}, {{574, 3}, {574, 4}}, {{576,
    1}}, {{577, 1}, {577, 4}}, {{578, 2}}, {{579, 3}}, {{580, 
   8}, {580, 10}}, {{581, 2}, {581, 4}}, {{582, 1}, {582, 3}}, {{585, 
   6}}, {{586, 1}, {586, 9}, {586, 10}}, {{588, 2}}, {{589, 
   2}}, {{590, 4}}, {{591, 1}, {591, 2}}, {{593, 10}}, {{594, 
   1}, {594, 2}, {594, 7}, {594, 10}}, {{595, 2}, {595, 8}}, {{596, 
   2}}, {{597, 1}}, {{598, 2}, {598, 4}}, {{599, 8}}, {{601, 1}, {601,
    10}}, {{604, 2}}, {{605, 4}}, {{606, 2}}, {{607, 1}}, {{608, 
   4}, {608, 10}}, {{609, 1}, {609, 10}}, {{610, 2}, {610, 3}}, {{612,
    1}, {612, 4}, {612, 9}}, {{613, 8}}, {{615, 1}, {615, 3}, {615, 
   8}}, {{616, 1}, {616, 2}, {616, 10}}, {{618, 2}}, {{619, 1}, {619, 
   4}}, {{623, 4}, {623, 6}}, {{624, 2}, {624, 9}}, {{625, 1}, {625, 
   2}, {625, 4}, {625, 9}, {625, 10}}, {{628, 6}}, {{629, 2}, {629, 
   4}, {629, 10}}, {{630, 1}, {630, 8}, {630, 9}}, {{631, 3}, {631, 
   10}}, {{633, 2}}, {{634, 6}}, {{635, 10}}, {{637, 8}}, {{639, 
   1}, {639, 2}, {639, 4}}, {{640, 1}, {640, 2}}, {{641, 8}}, {{642, 
   1}, {642, 3}}, {{643, 8}}, {{644, 2}, {644, 4}}, {{645, 1}, {645, 
   7}}, {{646, 1}, {646, 2}}, {{648, 2}}, {{649, 1}, {649, 7}, {649, 
   10}}, {{651, 1}, {651, 2}, {651, 8}}, {{652, 1}, {652, 4}}, {{654, 
   1}, {654, 2}}, {{655, 2}}, {{656, 6}}, {{658, 7}}, {{659, 2}, {659,
    6}, {659, 8}}, {{660, 1}, {660, 3}, {660, 6}}, {{661, 1}, {661, 
   3}}, {{663, 6}}, {{664, 1}, {664, 4}}, {{665, 10}}, {{666, 
   3}, {666, 4}, {666, 7}}, {{667, 3}}, {{668, 2}, {668, 6}}, {{670, 
   2}, {670, 6}, {670, 9}}, {{673, 2}}, {{674, 10}}, {{675, 
   8}}, {{676, 2}, {676, 8}, {676, 9}}, {{681, 1}, {681, 10}}, {{683, 
   2}}, {{684, 1}, {684, 3}, {684, 4}, {684, 7}}, {{685, 3}}, {{686, 
   2}, {686, 10}}, {{687, 1}, {687, 3}}, {{688, 3}, {688, 4}, {688, 
   6}, {688, 10}}, {{690, 3}, {690, 8}}, {{691, 1}, {691, 2}}, {{693, 
   2}, {693, 10}}, {{694, 3}}, {{695, 2}}, {{697, 3}}, {{699, 
   2}}, {{700, 1}}, {{703, 6}}, {{705, 1}, {705, 2}}, {{706, 2}, {706,
    8}}, {{708, 2}}, {{709, 2}}, {{710, 10}}, {{711, 9}}, {{712, 
   1}}, {{714, 1}, {714, 4}, {714, 8}}, {{715, 1}, {715, 2}, {715, 
   7}}, {{716, 2}}, {{717, 1}, {717, 4}}, {{720, 1}, {720, 2}}, {{721,
    4}, {721, 8}}, {{722, 4}}, {{723, 3}}, {{724, 1}, {724, 
   2}}, {{726, 1}, {726, 3}}, {{727, 1}, {727, 4}}, {{728, 2}, {728, 
   10}}, {{730, 1}, {730, 10}}, {{731, 4}, {731, 10}}, {{733, 
   3}}, {{736, 1}}, {{738, 10}}, {{739, 2}, {739, 3}, {739, 
   9}}, {{741, 1}, {741, 4}, {741, 7}}, {{742, 1}, {742, 3}}, {{743, 
   2}, {743, 4}}, {{744, 1}}, {{745, 1}}, {{746, 2}}, {{747, 
   1}}, {{748, 4}}, {{750, 1}, {750, 2}, {750, 3}}, {{751, 3}, {751, 
   8}}, {{753, 2}, {753, 3}}, {{754, 2}}, {{755, 10}}, {{756, 
   1}}, {{757, 7}}, {{759, 7}}, {{761, 2}}, {{762, 1}, {762, 
   4}}, {{763, 2}, {763, 3}, {763, 4}, {763, 8}}, {{765, 2}}, {{766, 
   1}, {766, 6}}, {{768, 10}}, {{769, 2}, {769, 3}, {769, 9}}, {{770, 
   6}}, {{771, 6}}, {{772, 1}}, {{774, 6}, {774, 8}}, {{775, 1}, {775,
    6}, {775, 10}}, {{776, 2}, {776, 4}}, {{777, 1}, {777, 3}}, {{778,
    8}}, {{779, 2}, {779, 6}}, {{780, 1}, {780, 2}, {780, 4}}, {{781, 
   2}, {781, 8}}, {{783, 3}}, {{784, 1}, {784, 3}}, {{786, 1}, {786, 
   2}, {786, 4}}, {{787, 7}}, {{789, 9}}, {{790, 1}, {790, 6}, {790, 
   9}}, {{792, 1}, {792, 8}}, {{794, 2}}, {{795, 8}}, {{796, 6}, {796,
    8}}, {{797, 8}}, {{798, 2}, {798, 6}, {798, 7}}, {{799, 
   1}}, {{800, 6}, {800, 8}}, {{801, 1}}, {{803, 2}, {803, 4}, {803, 
   10}}, {{804, 1}, {804, 2}, {804, 7}}, {{805, 1}}, {{807, 1}, {807, 
   4}, {807, 8}}, {{808, 8}}, {{809, 2}}, {{810, 1}, {810, 9}}, {{811,
    1}}, {{813, 6}}, {{814, 1}, {814, 2}, {814, 3}, {814, 4}, {814, 
   9}}, {{815, 2}, {815, 8}, {815, 10}}, {{816, 2}, {816, 3}, {816, 
   9}}, {{819, 1}, {819, 3}}, {{825, 2}, {825, 10}}, {{828, 
   3}}, {{829, 1}, {829, 3}}, {{831, 6}}, {{832, 1}, {832, 3}, {832, 
   4}}, {{833, 2}, {833, 8}}, {{834, 1}, {834, 4}, {834, 9}}, {{835, 
   1}, {835, 3}}, {{836, 10}}, {{837, 3}}, {{838, 2}}, {{839, 
   8}}, {{841, 3}}, {{843, 3}}, {{845, 2}, {845, 4}}, {{846, 
   10}}, {{847, 1}}, {{848, 2}, {848, 6}}, {{849, 1}}, {{850, 
   1}, {850, 4}, {850, 9}}, {{852, 8}}, {{853, 10}}, {{855, 
   1}}, {{856, 2}, {856, 10}}, {{857, 4}}, {{860, 4}}, {{861, 
   1}, {861, 3}, {861, 4}}, {{862, 1}}, {{863, 2}}, {{866, 6}}, {{867,
    1}}, {{868, 6}}, {{869, 6}}, {{870, 7}}, {{871, 1}, {871, 
   3}, {871, 8}}, {{873, 2}, {873, 4}}, {{874, 1}}, {{875, 6}, {875, 
   8}}, {{876, 4}}, {{877, 1}, {877, 7}}, {{879, 3}}, {{880, 1}, {880,
    6}, {880, 10}}, {{881, 2}}, {{882, 3}}, {{883, 4}}, {{884, 
   2}}, {{885, 2}}, {{888, 3}}, {{889, 1}, {889, 2}}, {{890, 2}, {890,
    4}, {890, 6}}, {{891, 4}}, {{892, 1}}, {{894, 1}, {894, 6}, {894, 
   10}}, {{895, 1}}, {{897, 3}}, {{898, 10}}, {{901, 1}, {901, 
   2}, {901, 8}}, {{906, 1}, {906, 2}, {906, 8}}, {{909, 3}, {909, 
   8}, {909, 9}}, {{910, 3}}, {{912, 1}}, {{913, 4}, {913, 7}}, {{915,
    2}}, {{916, 1}, {916, 8}}, {{917, 8}}, {{918, 6}}, {{919, 
   8}, {919, 9}}, {{921, 2}, {921, 8}}, {{922, 4}}, {{923, 2}}, {{924,
    1}, {924, 4}, {924, 7}}, {{925, 2}, {925, 4}}, {{926, 6}}, {{928, 
   6}}, {{930, 2}, {930, 9}}, {{931, 1}, {931, 6}}, {{934, 1}}, {{936,
    1}}, {{937, 1}, {937, 7}}, {{938, 4}, {938, 10}}, {{939, 1}, {939,
    2}, {939, 8}}, {{940, 1}, {940, 3}, {940, 9}, {940, 10}}, {{941, 
   2}}, {{943, 3}}, {{944, 2}}, {{945, 1}, {945, 9}}, {{946, 2}, {946,
    4}}, {{948, 3}, {948, 4}}, {{950, 2}, {950, 6}, {950, 8}}, {{951, 
   1}, {951, 4}, {951, 8}}, {{952, 4}}, {{953, 4}}, {{954, 1}}, {{955,
    2}, {955, 4}, {955, 7}}, {{956, 2}}, {{957, 1}}, {{960, 
   6}}, {{961, 8}}, {{963, 2}}, {{965, 2}}, {{966, 1}, {966, 
   2}}, {{967, 1}}, {{968, 2}}, {{969, 3}, {969, 8}}, {{970, 3}, {970,
    6}, {970, 9}}, {{972, 3}}, {{974, 2}}, {{975, 1}}, {{976, 
   1}, {976, 2}, {976, 6}}, {{979, 4}, {979, 8}, {979, 9}}, {{980, 
   4}}, {{981, 2}, {981, 4}}, {{982, 3}, {982, 8}}, {{984, 2}, {984, 
   3}, {984, 6}}, {{987, 1}, {987, 3}}, {{988, 6}}, {{989, 2}, {989, 
   10}}, {{990, 1}, {990, 3}}, {{991, 3}}, {{992, 4}}, {{994, 
   1}, {994, 2}, {994, 6}}, {{996, 2}, {996, 3}, {996, 4}, {996, 
   6}}, {{997, 1}}, {{998, 2}}, {{999, 1}, {999, 9}}, {{1000, 
   1}, {1000, 2}}}
```

So, we can see that using the bounds $1\le\text{n}\le10^3$ and $1\le\text{k}\le10$ we found $1419$ solutions. That number is found by using the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[2]:=Clear["Global`*"];
\[Alpha] = 10^3;
\[Beta] = 10^1;
f = Total@*Map[Length];
f[ParallelTable[
   If[PrimeQ[n^k + n - 1], {n, k}, Nothing], {n, 1, \[Alpha]}, {k, 
    1, \[Beta]}] //. {} -> Nothing]

Out[2]=1419
```

Extending the bounds to $1\le\text{n}\le10^4$ and $1\le\text{k}\le10^2$ gives $19235$ solutions.

---

I did a search to find solutions for $\text{n}=107$. I did find a solution for $1\le\text{k}\le5\cdot10^3$ because when $\text{k}=1400$ the number $\text{n}^\text{k}+\text{n}-1$ is prime.

I also searched for solutions of $\text{n}$ and $\text{k}$ such that $\text{k}\ne6\text{m}+5$ (where $\text{m}\in\mathbb{N}$). I did find solutions for $1\le\text{n}\le10^2$ and $1\le\text{k}\le10$:

```
In[3]:=Clear["Global`*"];
\[Alpha] = 10^2;
\[Beta] = 10^1;
ParallelTable[
  If[TrueQ[PrimeQ[n^k + n - 1] && IntegerQ[(k - 5)/6] == False], {n, 
    k}, Nothing], {n, 1, \[Alpha]}, {k, 1, \[Beta]}] //. {} -> Nothing

Out[3]={{{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 8}}, {{3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 
   4}, {3, 8}, {3, 10}}, {{4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}, {4, 6}, {4, 8}, {4, 
   9}}, {{5, 2}, {5, 6}, {5, 10}}, {{6, 1}, {6, 2}, {6, 4}, {6, 
   7}, {6, 10}}, {{7, 1}, {7, 3}}, {{8, 2}, {8, 6}, {8, 10}}, {{9, 
   1}, {9, 2}, {9, 4}, {9, 7}, {9, 10}}, {{10, 1}, {10, 2}, {10, 
   3}, {10, 4}, {10, 9}}, {{11, 2}, {11, 8}}, {{12, 1}, {12, 
   4}}, {{13, 2}, {13, 4}, {13, 10}}, {{15, 1}, {15, 2}, {15, 3}, {15,
    9}}, {{16, 1}, {16, 2}, {16, 3}, {16, 4}, {16, 8}, {16, 
   10}}, {{17, 4}, {17, 8}}, {{18, 3}, {18, 6}}, {{19, 1}, {19, 
   2}}, {{20, 2}, {20, 4}}, {{21, 1}, {21, 2}, {21, 3}}, {{22, 
   1}, {22, 7}}, {{23, 4}, {23, 6}}, {{24, 1}, {24, 2}, {24, 
   10}}, {{25, 3}, {25, 8}}, {{26, 2}, {26, 4}, {26, 10}}, {{27, 
   1}, {27, 3}, {27, 8}}, {{28, 2}, {28, 4}}, {{29, 10}}, {{30, 
   1}, {30, 2}, {30, 7}}, {{31, 1}, {31, 2}, {31, 4}, {31, 6}, {31, 
   10}}, {{33, 3}, {33, 4}}, {{34, 1}, {34, 6}}, {{35, 2}}, {{36, 
   1}, {36, 3}, {36, 6}}, {{37, 1}, {37, 7}}, {{38, 2}}, {{39, 
   2}, {39, 3}}, {{40, 1}, {40, 4}, {40, 10}}, {{41, 2}}, {{42, 
   1}}, {{43, 3}, {43, 4}}, {{44, 2}, {44, 4}}, {{45, 1}, {45, 
   2}}, {{46, 2}, {46, 3}, {46, 8}}, {{48, 2}}, {{49, 1}, {49, 
   7}, {49, 9}}, {{50, 2}, {50, 6}, {50, 8}}, {{51, 1}, {51, 3}, {51, 
   6}, {51, 10}}, {{52, 1}, {52, 3}}, {{53, 2}, {53, 6}}, {{54, 
   1}, {54, 2}, {54, 4}}, {{55, 1}, {55, 2}, {55, 3}}, {{56, 2}, {56, 
   6}}, {{57, 1}, {57, 9}}, {{58, 4}}, {{59, 2}, {59, 10}}, {{60, 
   2}, {60, 6}}, {{61, 7}, {61, 9}}, {{62, 8}}, {{63, 3}, {63, 
   6}}, {{64, 1}, {64, 2}}, {{65, 2}}, {{66, 1}, {66, 2}, {66, 
   8}, {66, 9}}, {{68, 2}, {68, 8}}, {{69, 1}, {69, 6}}, {{70, 
   1}, {70, 2}, {70, 7}, {70, 9}}, {{72, 4}}, {{73, 3}, {73, 
   6}}, {{74, 8}}, {{75, 1}, {75, 6}}, {{76, 1}, {76, 2}, {76, 
   6}, {76, 10}}, {{77, 4}, {77, 8}}, {{78, 3}}, {{79, 1}, {79, 
   9}}, {{81, 3}}, {{82, 1}}, {{83, 2}, {83, 6}}, {{84, 1}, {84, 
   8}}, {{85, 2}}, {{86, 2}}, {{87, 1}, {87, 3}, {87, 8}}, {{88, 
   8}}, {{89, 2}, {89, 10}}, {{90, 1}, {90, 10}}, {{91, 1}, {91, 
   6}}, {{92, 4}}, {{93, 2}, {93, 3}, {93, 4}, {93, 7}}, {{94, 
   2}, {94, 3}}, {{96, 1}, {96, 2}, {96, 3}, {96, 6}, {96, 10}}, {{97,
    1}}, {{98, 4}}, {{99, 1}, {99, 10}}, {{100, 1}, {100, 2}, {100, 
   3}, {100, 7}, {100, 8}}}
```

Comment: Thank you! Notably, this confirms conjecture $3$ for $k=9$ ($n=172$)

Comment: @MichałZapała You're welcome, I am glad that I could help you.